# Creating a dictionary from text file and adjusting text file

Tags: file, dictionary, text

I am trying to create a dictionary from a text file but I can't get it to work.

The format of the text file is similar to this:

1a1c:ME

ERASDGGJRIDNF

3a3b:JE

GSHDBDBDVBDHD

I tried to do line.split(':') but I keep on getting an error message that 2 values were expected but there is only one instead.

I would really appreciate it if someone could help me out.

Comment: So a dictionary is a list of value pars with a hash for the key.  The THIS:THAT is easy to understand but what do you want to do with the other line in CAPITALS? You can't split those.

Comment: The second line is supposed to continue from the first one. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Yes.. and no "supposed to continue from the first one".. is there a 0x0D and or 0x0A (CR\LF) between those lines?  For instance.. (your example).. am I seeing `1a1c:ME\nERASDGGJRIDNF` or `1a1c:MEERASDGGJRIDNF`?